# Second Order Differential Equation find the solution of for a particular values

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am having difficulty solving this question. Let $xy''-y'=0$ (1). The book says try a solution of the form $y = x^r$. Is this a solution for some $r$? If so find all such $r$.

So I found the derivatives of $y = x^r$ (2). Them being: $y'= x^rlog(x)$ (3) and $y''=x^rlog^2(x)$ (4). I then substituted (3) and (4) the derivatives into the equation (1), as follows:$$x(x^rlog^2(x))-x^rlog(x)=$$ Then, $$x.x^rlog^2(x)-x^rlog(x)=$$ Then taking a factor of $x^rlog(x)$ out the front, giving (not sure if I can do this): $$x^rlog(x)(x.x^rlog(x)-1)=$$ Where do I go from here to find whether this is a solution or not and what are the values of $r$. By the way, the answer in the back of the book is: $y=x^r$ is a solution for $r=0$ and $r=2$. All I need is how to get there.

Comment: The derivative must be $\;\frac d{dx}(x^r)=rx^{r-1}\;$

Comment: The OP's mistake seems to be that they are using $(x^r)'=x^r\log x$ and $(x^r\log x)'=x^r(\log x)^2$. Actually, as mentioned in passing in answers below, $(x^r)'=rx^{r-1}$ (and the derivative of $x^r\log x$ is not $x^r(\log x)^2$ either, but this is offtopic to solve the question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put

$$y=x^r\implies y'=rx^{r-1}\implies y''=r(r-1)x^{r-2}\implies$$

$$xy''-y'=r(r-1)x^{r-1}-rx^{r-1}=x^{r-1}\left(r(r-1)-r\right)=0\iff\begin{cases}r=0\\{}\\\text{or}\\{}\\r=2\end{cases}$$

Comment: Thanks. I substituted your derivatives in and got $x.r(r-1)x^{r-2}-rx^{r-1}$. Then should I put in $r$ for 0 and 2 and get the equation equal to 0 to say that it is a solution? Can you show me how to do it please.

Comment: @AlexRodriguez Look at the second line of calculations: in the rightmost expression you have that it **must be** $\;r(r-1)-r=0\iff r(r-1)=r\iff r=0\;,\;\;or\;\;r-1=1\iff r=2\;$ , otherwise the identity with zero isn't fulfilled.

Answer (score 0):

Try
$$
(x^ay')'=x^ay''+ax^{a-1}y'=x^{a-1}(xy''+ay')
$$
to find that $a=-1$ gives the form of the given differential equation, and thus
$$
x^{-1}y'=C ⟹ y'=Cx ⟹ y = \tilde Cx^2+D
$$